# Powers of ten addition with negative power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been stumped by my nephew's algebra homework.

He has a question:

$10^5 + 10^{-3}=$?

The multi-choice answers were:

$10^{-5},10^{15},10^{3},10^{2},10^{5},10^{8}$

(to 1 s.f.)

I thought it was as simple as adding the powers - therefore being $10^2$. Apparently not. Can someone help so I can assist?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem was $10^5 + 10^{-3}$, and not $10^5 \cdot 10^{-3}$? Because none of the answers given is correct for the question you wrote. The right answer is 10000.001, which is not $10$ raised to any integer power.

Comment: The answer is none of the above. Are there other instructions you are leaving out (like rounding to the nearest whole number)?

Comment: None of the answers are correct.

Comment: Sorry yes - there is small print saying 1 signifcant figure

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646922/why-is-everything-except-0-to-the-power-of-0-always-1/2646949#2646949 and read the first half of my answer. Then, substitute $x = 10$, $a = 5$, $b = -3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer to the question is $10^5$!!!

Rounded to 1 s.f. (1 significant figure) $10^5 + 10^{-3} = 10000.001$ gives $10^5$.

In school books they write quite often things like

$$10000.001 = 10000 \mbox{ (1 s.f.) }$$

and mean that the number on the right-hand side is the result after rounding the number on the left-hand side to 1 significant figure.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing two identities. The one you're using incorrectly is:

$$10^5\color{red}{\times}10^{-3}=10^{5+(-3)}=10^2\color{red}{\neq}10^5\color{blue}{+}10^{-3}$$

For the right answer, you need to know the values of $10^5$ and $10^{-3}$ **individually** and then **add** **them**. The correct answer is approximately close to the answer you'll get (the problem should ask you to select the *closest* match after rounding off).

Comment: You're right in the small print (badly photocopied) it advises to 1s.f.

Answer (score 2):

$10^5 + 10^{-3} = 10^5 + \frac{1}{10^3} = \frac{10^8+1}{10^3}$.

Clearly the answer matches none of the given choices.

Answer (score 2):

Adding two powers of ten never gives a new power of ten. You can see this easily by considering two numbers with a single $1$ (either before or after the decimal point) and otherwise all zeroes. Adding them together either gives a number with two $1$'s and otherwise all zeroes, or a single $2$ and otherwise all zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that by $10^5+10^{-3}$ you meant $10^5\times 10^{-3}$.

---

Say we have a value $x$ and we want to raise it to a power $n$. This means that we multiply $x$ by itself $n$ times. $$x^n = \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot\ldots\cdot x}_{n\text{ times.}}\tag1$$ It is confusing to most people when we say that $x^0 =1$, because how can we multiply $x$ by itself $0$ times? Here, we have to look at one of the *Power Rules*.

The first power rule is as follows: $$x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a + b}.\tag2$$ This is provable from $(1)$. Since $x^a$ and $x^b$ are all products of $x$, then when we multiply them together, the number of times $x$ is being multiplied by itself in total is of course $a + b$ times. Therefore, the product of $x^a$ and $x^b$ is always $x^{a+b}$.

So this means that since $n = n + 0$, we get that $x^n = x^n\cdot x^0$. Therefore, $x^0$ must be equal to $1$. $$x^0 = 1.$$

---

Now, substitute $x = 10$, $a = 5$, and $b = -3$ in $(2)$. You should have, $$\begin{align} 10^5\times 10^{-3} &= 10^{5+(-3)} \\ &= 10^{5-3} \\ &= 10^2.\end{align}$$